# How to copy a forumla in excel using only the keyboard?

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts

I run into this situation a lot.  I have a column of data (A) and I created a formula in B1 that I wish to copy from B2 to B5.  This is just a tiny example, because usually I'm dealing with thousands of rows.

What I want to do is to select B1, press ctrl-C to copy and then somehow select the range B2-B5 by using column A as some sort of reference point.  IIRC, a long time ago with Excel (Lotus 1-2-3?) that you could do this all with they keyboard using ctrl/arrow/end/home key combinations.

Thanks!

```
    A   B
1   10  =2*A1
2   20  
3   30  
4   40  
5   50
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remnant's answer is a good one. This one allows you to do the same thing to the left or if there are empty columns in between.

As you say, in B1 do <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> then

<kbd>Left-Arrow</kbd> Select A1

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Down Arrow</kbd> to select down to the last filled cell in Column A

<kbd>Right-Arrow</kbd> to get to corresponding Column B cell

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> to select Column B back to original selection

<kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd>

Comment: Use keyboard to select B1.  Ctrl-C, left arrow, C-S-DA, RA at this point cell B1 is selected (not the correspnding Col B cell)

Comment: Woops, fixed now. It should have just been C-DA to get to end of Column A.

Comment: Awesome!  Or "Enter" to paste as well.

Comment: You know I've read the message "Select Destination and Press Enter ..." about a million times, but until you said that, it never actually registered in my brain :). Glad I could help.

Comment: Forget Ctrl-C and Ctrl-V.  Do everything else and finish with Ctrl-D for Fill Down.

Comment: @dkusleika, the Keyboarding King has spoken! Damn, I've learned two new things by answering this question. I never remember Ctrl-D. The funny thing is I use Ctrl-Enter, to the point where I'll F2 back into the cell just so I can use it.

Answer (score 1):

Try Ctrl-C to copy cell B2 then navigate with arrow key to select B3. Hold shift then Page Down to go down quickly in column B to the desired point (fine tune with arrow key). Ctrl-V to paste.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest and most convenient way is:

1. Select cell B1
2. Double-click the little square in the bottom-right corner

This will auto-fill your formula down to cell B5.

Note that if there is a missing row in column A then it will only auto-fill down to the missing row.

Comment: Double-click is not a key board command.

Comment: I agree. Just thought I'd offer it up as it seems relevant in this instance and not everybody knows about that shortcut

Answer (score 0):

Sara almost has it, but there are some modifications

Copy cell B2 with Ctrl+C, while holding the shift key arrow down to cell B5 (selects all the cells). Ctrl+V to paste (fills the cells with the modified formula)

Comment: My method does the same as yours for the example, James. The formula updates correctly if the OP requires 2* the adjacent cell.

Comment: On second look your right it does, I got lost when you copied cell B2 then navigated to it.